# Question about proof of onto

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> define $T:P(R) \rightarrow P(R)$ by $T(f(x))= \int_{0}^x f(t) dt$. Prove T is injective but not surjective.

I have a proof question about surjective:

Here is a proof:
To show T is not surjective, need to show that $T(f(x)) \neq (P (R))$, which is the codomain.

Then take f(x)=1, then f(x) can be written $1+0 \cdot x^2+ 0 \cdot x^3...$
Take $\int_{0}^x f(t)=1$. 
Then $\int_{0}^x a_0+a_1 \cdot t+a_2 \cdot t^2+ a_3 \cdot t^3+... dt=1$

$a_0 x+\frac{a_1 x^2}{2}+...=1$

For all i, there is no $a_i$ in the left-hand side of the above equation equivalent to 1.
Hence the infinite polynomial doesn't have a preimage. Hence not onto.

My question is

> For all i, there is no $a_i$ in the left-hand side of the above equation equivalent to 1

Does that mean since by injectivity ( which has been proven), we have $a_i$=0, then we can't find a single $a_i$ such that $a_i= 1$, hence not onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what “For all $i$, there is no $a_i$ in the left-hand side of the above equation equivalent to $1$” means. But I do know this: if $p(x)\in P(\mathbb R)$, then $T\bigl(p(x)\bigr)(0)=0$, and therefore there is no $p(x)\in P(\mathbb R)$such that $T\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=1$.

Comment: Ahh I see from injectivity, the T(p(x)) is limited to 0, so T(p(x) is never equal to the whole codomain? Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: No. The injectivity of $T$ is not relevant here and it is not true that the codomain of $T$ is limited to $0$. The codomain of $T$ is $P(\mathbb R)$. It turns out that all polynomials $p(x)$ from the image of $T$ are such that $p(0)=0$. Since not all elements of $P(\mathbb R)$ have this property, $T$ is not surjective.